# How to copy HDFS files from one cluster to another cluster by preserving the modification time

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, distcp, bigdata

I have to move some HDFS files from my production cluster to dev cluster. I have to test some operations on HDFS files after moving to dev cluster based on the file modification time. Need files with different dates to test it in dev.

I tried doing with DISTCP, Modification time is updating with the current time in that. i checked the Distcp by using many parameters that I found here [distcp version2 guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp2.html)

Is there any other way to get the files without changing modification time? or can i change the modification time manually after getting the files into hdfs ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-pt` flag with the `hadoop distcp` command. This will `p`reserve `t`imestamp (modification time) of the file that is distcp'd.

```
hadoop distcp -pt hdfs://src_cluster/file hdfs://dest_cluster/file
```

Tested with Hadoop-2.7.3

Refer latest [Distcp Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html)